# Datetime changing ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have an Event  and want to add for their start and end date 1 day. COde:

```
params[:event][:start_time] = [:event][:start_time] + 1.day
        params[:event][:end_time] = [:event][:start_time] + 1.day
```

And this should add to started and ended time 1 day, but it doesnt worked.

Error is :

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Your variable holds Array instance (in [hash_key, hash_value] format), so it doesn't expect Symbol in [] method

Comment: can you show us what value `params[:event][:start_time]` holds?

Comment: @shivam can you tell me how?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with params so please post log

Comment: @AmitSharma im just new at rails. Can u tell me how?

Comment: when you call any action it will get printed on terminal where you have started the server with rails s command

Answer (score 2):

You have two error here. The first one, is that you are missing the `params` in the second part of the expression, therefore you are assigning an array of array to params effectively overriding the `params`.

```
params[:event][:start_time] = [:event][:start_time] + 1.day
```

should be

```
params[:event][:start_time] = params[:event][:start_time] + 1.day
```

The second issue is that the values stored in `params` are `String`, not dates or integers. Therefore you need to cast the value

```
params[:event][:start_time] = Time.new(params[:event][:start_time]) + 1.day
```

There are two additional potential issues: (1) you are overriding the original parameters which is never a good practice (2) the value could be `nil` causing a crash in your app.

```
event = params[:event].presence || {}
event[:start_time] = Time.parse(event[:start_time]) + 1.day if event[:start_time]
event[:end_time]   = Time.parse(event[:end_time]) + 1.day   if event[:end_time]
```

Now the `event` variable holds the correct Hash of params.

Comment: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer got the same error (

Comment: There was a small typo in one example, but the final code was correct. Also, try to follow the instruction I provided, they will help you to understand the code (rather than just copying the solution).

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  (1..10).each do |i|
    params[:event][:user_id] = current_user.id
    start_time = DateTime.new(params[:event]['start_time(1i)'].to_i, params[:event]['start_time(2i)'].to_i, params[:event]['start_time(3i)'].to_i, params[:event]['start_time(5i)'].to_i, params[:event]['start_time(4i)'].to_i)
    end_time = DateTime.new(params[:event]['end_time(1i)'].to_i, params[:event]['end_time(2i)'].to_i, params[:event]['end_time(3i)'].to_i, params[:event]['end_time(5i)'].to_i, params[:event]['end_time(4i)'].to_i)
    if i > 1
      params[:event][:start_time] = (start_time + "#{i}".to_i.day)
      params[:event][:end_time] = (end_time + "#{i}".to_i.day)
    end
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.save
  end
  redirect_to events_path
end
```

Comment: still doesnt work, error in "+" symbol. Maybe problem in activesupport

Comment: try to get value of params[:event][:start_time]

Comment: no implicit conversion of nil into String error anyway

Comment: paste your params[:event][:start_time] value here

Comment: i've got it from form where
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :end_time %>
  </div>

Comment: invalid date in first line

Comment: events created but time didnt change

Comment: means? What happened exactly? Please explain

Comment: time which i set in form in other events the same. But i need +1 day for each.  But they created!

Comment: nope, problem in first line, its totally scared me. I just need to add 1 day of each other events :D problem in date.parse

Comment: "start_time(1i)"=>"2015", "start_time(2i)"=>"5", "start_time(3i)"=>"28", "start_time(4i)"=>"06", "start_time(5i)"=>"21", "end_time(1i)"=>"2015", "end_time(2i)"=>"5", "end_time(3i)"=>"28", "end_time(4i)"=>"06", "end_time(5i)"=>"21"

This was your params...right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78986/discussion-between-damir-nurgaliev-and-user123).

Answer (score 1):

```
params[:event][:start_time] = DateTime.parse(params[:event][:start_time]) + 1.days
params[:event][:end_time] =  DateTime.parse(params[:event][:end_time]) + 1.day
```

or

```
params[:event][:start_time] =  DateTime.parse(params[:event][:start_time]).next_day
```

Comment: no implicit conversion of nil into String error anyway ((

Comment: you should check the values of `params[:event][:start_time]`, maybe it is invalid.

Comment: checked, all is valid